# Redirecting SSH through a machine

Tags: networking, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm looking for the simplest way to SSH from my local machine to a remote server through a server in the middle.

If there's a permanent way to do this even better.

Comment: "ssh -L" as a one off, stunnel for longer term use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host remote.example.com
    ProxyCommand ssh middle.example.com nc %h %p
```

Comment: Do you know if this will work with sshfs? Will I be able to mount a folder on the remote server through the middle server?

Comment: Not sure, it'd be fairly easy to give it a shot.

Comment: Excellent! This is incredibly useful...

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be just to `ssh middlebox` and just run `ssh remotebox` from there. You can also use your locally-stored SSH key for authentication against the remote machine by using SSH agent forwarding, which requires you to run `ssh-agent` locally and set `AgentForwarding on`, ideally in your SSH config file. See `man ssh_config` and `man ssh-agent` for details.

Comment: If you're going to do this, you have to trust the box in the middle. It can abuse your agent forwarding, hijack your session, etc.